# Ubuntu 13.10 and Nvidia. Second Monitor causes graphics settings to reset

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to get a second monitor on my laptop, plugged in through HDMI. I can get the second screen to be detected and display stuff, but every minute or two the graphics will freak out, both screens will go black, and all my windows will appear on one monitor (it seems to switch between monitors). The other monitor will be disabled when this happens. Obviously its impossible to get anything done with this happening.

Here is the output from lspci -v | grep NVIDIA

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 435M] (rev a1)
```

I have tried changing the xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/ and it doesn't seem to do anything. I have deleted it, filled it with gibberish, and there is no effect either way. Here is my xorg.conf. I created this by going into `nvidia-settings` and saved the config file.

```
Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS PB278"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 99.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     59.6
    Option         "Monitor-HDMI"
    Option         "RightOf Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 435M"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option "metamodes" "1366x768 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo 0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "Off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It feels like I have tried every combination of Nvidia driver and bumblebee install and nothing seems to make any difference. Sometimes I will get the screens to be stable for a few hours, but then when I turn off my computer the fix goes away. The only thing I have learned for certain is that bumblebee seems to completely disable my display, and I have to go into safemode to remove it before anything will work. It is not feasible for me to fix this once and then never turn off my computer again.

Another, possibly unconnected, issue is that my second monitor is coming up as maxium 1920x1080, when it is actually 2560x1440. My laptop itself is only 1368x768 so I really need the extra screen space. I would be satisfied if I can just get the second monitor to work, then I will just use that screen and keep my laptop disabled. Thus far I have been unable to do that. Any suggestions?